# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(1-1/n)^k$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem is stated as:

> Show that $s_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(1-1/n)^k$ diverges as $n\rightarrow \infty$ given that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ diverges and that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kx^k$ is 1.

**My attempt**

We want to show that $s_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(1-1/n)^k$ diverges as n tends to infinity. This is equivalent to show that:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(1-1/n)^k = \infty$$

We see that if we can move the limit inside the summation, we can show that $a_k(1-1/n)^k \rightarrow a_k$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ which would give us $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ which clearly diverges.

Since $(1-1/n) < 1 \forall n \geq 1$, we are within our radius of convergence, which means we have uniform convergence for the given series. Hence, it's possible to move in the limit inside our summation, and we get:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ which is given to be divergent. Hence, we have shown that the given series diverges!

I'm a bit unsure whether my method is correct, since moving the limit inside the summation also means I somehow have to change the upper bound of the summation from n to $\infty$. Maybe there's a way to show this with an inequality. I'd be glad if you could provide me tips for this.

My professor had another solution on his mind, he used the fact that $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(1-1/n)^k \geq \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(1-k/n) \geq 1/2 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_k $ which then by comparision has to diverge. However, I don't really understand the last step, and I'd be glad if somehow could explain that to me.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume $a_n\ge0$? It seems your professor is using [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), the lower bound $1-\frac kn\ge\frac12$ for $1\le k\le\frac n2$ and he is discarding the (nonnegative) terms of the series from $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor+1$ to $n$.

Comment: If $a_k \ge 0$, then for $k \le \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ you have $ 1 - \frac{k}{n} \ge 1/2$ and for $k \ge \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, $ \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)a_k \ge 0$.

Comment: I do not get the uniform convergence you mentioned, since the ramaining terms actually converges not.

Comment: You'd better check the definition of uniform convergence. Your teacher's method is correct and clear.

Comment: @nejimban Yes, that's correct, the terms are positive.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thank you, I understand now :)